# My code does not show the Date & Time, how do I make it work? Also, can I click the button again to hide/show the date and time

Tags: javascript, html

I created a button that showed show the current date & time. My problem is that when I click on the button again it does not hide the date and time. can you help me?

I've tried:

HTML:

```
<div id="al">
   <button id="btnTimeDate" type="button">Time & Date</button>

   <p id="timeDate"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("btnTimeDate").addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
  document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = Date.();
}
```

But when I click it does not work.

What I have now and it works but I want it to be less cluttered & for the user to click the button to show/hide the time & date.

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('date_time_button').innerHTML = Date()"> Click and see Date and Time.</button>

<p id="date_time_button"></p>
```

Comment: Have you use jquery or not ??

Comment: Don't want to use jquery at this moment.

Comment: Because using jquery you can do this easily.

Comment: Understandable. I'm trying to get this work with out jquery. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your JavaScript code. If you remove the . in Date.(); it should work.

Update: I have wrapped the code sample with a snippet so you could run and see for yourself. If your code is not working, then you could check if you are accessing the page directly through file system in your browser, or is it on a server like http://example.com/sample-page.html or http://localhost/sample-page.html

Sometimes JavaScript may get restricted if it's not coming from a server. Or it is possible that you haven't refreshed your browser's cache before testing again. This might result in JavaScript not getting loaded, if it's not directly embedded in the same page's html code, but linked to an external .js file.

```js
var clickState = 0;
document.getElementById("btnTimeDate").onclick = function(){
  if (clickState == 0) {
    document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = Date();
    clickState = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = "";
    clickState = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnTimeDate">Get Date</button>
<div id="timeDate"></div>
```

Note: I've noticed a minor syntax error in the first line of the JavaScript above as well. Functions should be called with () added after their names, however it was working without them when I checked in the snippet tool as well. But just in case, I've corrected that mistake. Sorry for missing that before. That code block might have also get immediately triggered without waiting for the click event so I edited that in a way to completely encapsulate the code inside an onclick event function attached to the DOM element's id instead. So this should now work regardless.

Another solution might be to trigger this function on button's onclick even within html, like so:

```js
var clickState = 0;
function displayDate() {
  if (clickState == 0) {
    document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = Date();
    clickState = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = "";
    clickState = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnTimeDate" onclick="displayDate()">Get Date</button>
<div id="timeDate"></div>
```

These should all work. However, the date value would be changing each time you trigger this function. So I'd recommend you to get the date when the page loads, and just hide and show this element with the button's event instead so that the value does not change. So I'm adding an extra snippet bellow which does just that:

```js
var dateDiv = document.getElementById("timeDate");
dateDiv.innerHTML = Date();
dateDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("btnTimeDate").onclick = function(){
  if (dateDiv.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    dateDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    dateDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnTimeDate">Show/Hide Date</button>
<div id="timeDate"></div>
```

Comment: tried it also but it still doesn't do anything when I click on the button.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your feedback and added working snippets for your review to see if it's working for you or not as well. Sorry for the delayed answer. @user2771077 I hope this helps now. Cheers!

Comment: I also did not realize that you wanted to toggle between displaying and hiding date within an html element. So I'll edit my answer yet again to make it more useful for you @user2771077

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to solve your problem. But the cleaner and the faster way is to modify your displayDate function like this:

```
document.getElementById("btnTimeDate").addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
  if(document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = Date();
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

Also please note that you have a syntax error in your current code. Remove the `"."` in the `"Date.()"`

EDIT: Expected functionality [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k79tymwn/)

Comment: I have tried this but every time I click the button it does nothing.

Comment: Your code seems to be what I want but when I put the javascript in my .js file and the keep the html part the way it is like on JSFiddle but it does not run like on JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loadFunction()
        {
            document.getElementById("timeDate").style.display = "none";
        }

        function displayDate() {
            var dateField;

            dateField = document.getElementById("timeDate");

            dateField.innerHTML = Date();

            dateField.style.display = (dateField.style.display == "")?"none":"";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadFunction();">
    <div id="al">
        <button id="btnTimeDate" type="button" onclick="displayDate();">Time & Date</button>
        <p id="timeDate"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put entire code in HTML frame on JSFiddle and try... I tried. It is working as expected

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I moved the script into javascript and the html part into the html panel. It does work thank you but I need it to call it from my script.js page so most of the code is not on my index.html just a snip it. the rest would link back. So i would not have my code cluttered. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

U need the word  { new }

var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;

Answer (score 0):

You have to encapsulate your javascript code inside,

```
window.onload = () => {
    // your javascript
};
```

That is,

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById("btnTimeDate").addEventListener("click", displayDate);

    function displayDate() {
        document.getElementById("timeDate").innerHTML = Date();
    }
};
```

your script runs before the dome is ready!

Here's a plunker implementation https://plnkr.co/edit/xue9l0wiriGitM8Tuz6c?p=preview

Comment: also note to remove the "." (period) in Date.() It should just be Date() No periods in between

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the following code :

```
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
          <script type="text/javascript"> 
             function show_now() { 
             var my_time = new Date();
             alert(my_time); 
           }
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <input type=button value="Show Time" onclick="show_now();">
      </body>
  </html>
```

I hope this helps you.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I see the code but I don't want for an alert to pop up. What I need is for the user to click the button to show the date & time and then to click it again to hide it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the following code :

```
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
          <script type="text/javascript"> 
              function show_now() { 
              var myDiv = document.getElementById("date_time_button")
              var my_time = new Date();
              if (myDiv.style.display === "block"){
                 myDiv.style.display = "none";    
              }else{            
                myDiv.style.display = "block";
                myDiv.innerHTML= my_time
             }
          }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>

        <input type=button value="Show Time" onclick="show_now();">
        <p id="date_time_button"></p>

     </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: I tried it on js fiddle and nothing seems to happen when I click on the button. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Can you check it following link:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show    
With put above code.

Comment: Have you checked?